# How to store data in Elastic search?

Tags: vue.js, elasticsearch, vue-component, magento2

I am working on to **store** , **wishlist items in server in Vue + magento setup**

How to store data in elastic search ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u didn't disabled anything default from settings, elasticsearch does for you when a field is not stored (default) and the `_source` field is enabled (default too).

> By default, Elasticsearch keeps a copy of all the JSON documents you offer it for indexing in a field called _source . You get a copy of this stored data on each query that matches the document. So yes: you are able to store your data in Elasticsearch and retrieve it too.

How ElasticSearch works: https://medium.com/tech-explained/can-elasticsearch-store-data-4b840308ea6f

Comment: can we store data in elastic search & use it in Vue magento 2 ? like storing wishlist items for customer & display it in wishlist page for each customer ?